# Linux problem-- I encountered a problem when i use if then elif fi

Tags: linux, shell

I am running this simple code to find the bug in my problem.When I am running this, it will give the result 3pt 3pt instead of 3pt 4pt.  I do not know what is wrong with this, can anybody help me?

```
define -a array
array=("4pt" "3pt")
for i in ${array[@]}
do 
   if [ ${i}=="3pt" ]
   then
     test_name="3pt"
   else
     test_name="4pt"
   fi
   echo ${test_name}
done
```

When i further type in echo ${i} behind echo ${test*name}, the echo{i} will give 3pt 4pt, so it does loop. If it loop, why echo ${test_*name } only give 3pt 3pt?

Comment: Did you run your script through shellcheck?  It'll tell you exactly what your bug is.

Comment: Use `[ "$i" = "3pt" ]`, or since you depend on arrays anyway, `[[ $i == "3pt" ]]`.

Comment: You also should specify what shell you are using. You just tagged this _shell_, which means POSIX shell.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding space in your if statement

`if [ ${i} == "3pt" ]`

Comment: `If` is not a keyword in shell

Comment: You are correct updated answer. Autocorrect...

Comment: You are using quotes exactly wrong.  You could write `if [ "${i}" == 3pt ]`, but most style guides would suggest `if [ "${i}" == "3pt" ]`, although the quotes around `3pt` are not needed.  Also note that `=` is more portable, and should be preferred over `==`.